# Why is $\{(1/(n+1),n)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a subanalytic set?

Tags: analyticity, real-algebraic-geometry

I have a question about subanalytic sets. Why is $\{(1/(n+1),n)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a subanalytic set but its projection onto $\mathbf{R}\times \{0\}$ is not?

Comment: How far did you get with applying the definition of subanalytic?

Comment: Actually this is a new concept for me, and I know semianalytic and subanalytic sets are similar to semialgebraic sets. But I couldn't figure this out by its definition.

Comment: have you tried : http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/raag/?